# How to return a string instead of system.object[] using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a function

```
function Build-Exec($path,$param1,$param2,$param3,$param4)
{
    $var = @($path,$param1,$param2,$param3,$param4) -join " "  
    return $var 
}
```

when i call it it returns

```
System.Object[]
```

How can i make it return a string?

example usage

```
$var1 = Build-Exec("1","2","3","4","5") 

Write-Output $var1
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Maybe the variable names are mistyped, but since the sample doesn't have actual usage, it's just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that isn't how you define or call parameters for a function in PowerShell

```bsh
function Build-Exec
{
    Param ($path,$param1,$param2,$param3,$param4)
    $var = @($path,$param1,$param2,$param3,$param4) -join " "  
    return $var 
}
```

Calling the function

```bsh
$var1 = Build-Exec "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
Write-Output $var1
1 2 3 4 5
```

When you include the commas, you are passing the first param a string array.